# Defining new CellStyle Protocol -SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I wanted to create CellStyle protocol similar to ButtonStyle but facing issue.

```
protocol CellStyle {
    associatedtype Body: View
    typealias Configuration = CellStyleConfiguration

    func makeBody(configuration: Self.Configuration) -> Self.Body

}

struct CellStyleConfiguration {
    struct Title: View {
        var text: String
        var body: some View {
            Text(text)
        }
      }
    var title: CellStyleConfiguration.Title
}
```

I Wanted to create cellView and apply cellType Protocol to it. Cell view will have only Text(). image and other stuff will be applied thru CellType protocol

Comment: What is your issue?

Comment: func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        HStack(spacing: 20) {
            Image(systemName: "paintpalette")
            VStack {
                configuration.content
                Text(subtext)
            }
           
        }
    }
>>> configuration.content and  Text(subtext) is not aligned